How does Sharing Set for Customer Community Login Users Work

Hi Im trying open access to some specific custom community login users on knowledge articles. And as that license does not support roles or sharing settings. I think that the way to go is through sharing sets.
Now when I create the sharing set, it offers me to apply it to the Knowledge object, however Im not sure on how this can help me to open visibility to a specific set of knowledge articles to my community users.
How is this matching performed? I cant find any account lookup on user object.
And Im assuming the User picklist indicates that whoever community user whose associated contact has a lookup to the same account that the owner of the knowledge articles is related to will have access to it.
However as I said, I dont know what is this relationship between an internal (sales) user and a specific account.
Because that way I could just associate all the community users to a specific account looked up by the user who is going to own the set of articles I want to share with them.
Any ideas on how can this be achieved?

I would look at Data Categories - these can be assigned to profiles, roles, permission sets, permission set groups

Remember that the User record for a community user has reference to the Contact for that user, and Contact has an Account reference. You can access the Contact for the User in a Sharing Set.
